# Issue Accessing DateTime Value (Unicode object has no attribute 'strftime')

Tags: django, datetime, django-views

I have an AJAX processed view that takes several pieces of information, two of which are unicode datetime values.

However, when I try to access the datetime values (start/end) directly from the object, it seems that it is still unicode.

I thought saving converted to datetime?

```
lid = int(postdata['lid'])
location = Group.objects.get(id=lid)
pgid = int(postdata['pgid'])
program = Group.objects.get(id=pgid)
start = postdata['start']
end = postdata['end']
eid = int(postdata['eid'])
creator = Employee.objects.get(id=eid)
description = postdata['description']

shift = ReliefShift()
shift.start = start
shift.end = end
shift.creator = creator
shift.description = description
shift.location = location
shift.program = program
shift.save()

alertModule = 'Relief Shifts Available'
alertMessage = 'A new relief shift has been posted for {0} from {1} to {2}. Visit the <a href="/staff/program/open-relief-shifts/">Relief Shifts page</a> for more details and to sign up.'.format(shift.location, shift.start.strftime('%b %d @ %I:%M%p'), shift.end.strftime('%b %d @ %I:%M%p'))
```

Comment: Where did you get `postdata`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `shift.save()` will save a datetime to the database, but it won't update `shift`. You could reload the shift object from the database after saving it, by calling [`refresh_from_db`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.refresh_from_db)

```
shift.start = <unicode string>
shift.save()
# At this point, shift.start will still be a string
shift.refresh_from_db()

# refresh_from_db is new in Django 1.8. In early versions you would do:
shift = Shift.objects.get(pk=shift.pk)
```

It's not good practice to read values directly from the post data. It would be better to use a [form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/) or [model form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/modelforms/). Django will take care of converting the values into datetime objects, and you will be able to access the datetimes from `form.cleaned_data`, or from the instance if you are using model forms.

Comment: Yup, that's it. refresh_from_db() is the answer. Interestingly, though, I tried shift = Shift.objects.get(pk=shift.pk) and it didn't update.

Comment: Using `shift = Shift.objects.get(pk=shift.pk)` should work if `refresh_from_db` does. Maybe you did `Shift.objects.get(pk=shift.pk)` but did not assign the result to `shift`. Using `id` instead of `pk` won't make any difference as long as your primary key is `id`.

Comment: Does it matter if it's pk? I used id.

Comment: If it's a modelform, why can't you just do `x = shift.save()` then get `x.start`?

Comment: @trpt4him That's why I suggested using a model form in my answer. If the form were valid, you would call `shift = form.save()`, then `shift.start` would be a datetime.

Comment: This is 100% personal opinion and there are definitely some instances - like this - where issues crop up, but I find modelforms and the entire Django form system to be a lot of overhead without a built-in means of granular template control.